# flutter stuck on running xcode build

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

Flutter stuck on running xcode build; the verbose shows that it get stuck at here,

```
[  +14 ms] Running Xcode build...
    [  +20 ms] executing: [/Users/navodsanthana/AndroidStudioProjects/flash-chat-flutter/ios/] /usr/bin/env xcrun xcodebuild
    -configuration Debug VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING=YES -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner
    BUILD_DIR=/Users/navodsanthana/AndroidStudioProjects/flash-chat-flutter/build/ios -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64
    SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/9_/0bt_4fkx6b3c117b__3dg0280000gn/T/flutter_tools.05FMSK/flutter_build_log_pipe.fnajhb/pipe_to
    _stdout FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
```

Comment: Go to terminal inside type ```flutter clean``` and try again, it happens sometimes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Delete Xcode/DerivedData
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter run`

Comment: Did you change app name Runner to appname?

Comment: It worked!! It takes some to build the app so be patient that's what I found out.

Comment: Where is this folder?

Comment: User/Library/Developer/Xcode in my device

Answer (score 4):

When I was running my project from Android Studio, it was just stuck, tried cleaning and everything but no progress.

Here is what I did:

- Try opening the project in Xcode and run it from there.
- If there are any issues, it will show them.
- Fix those issues (For me it was adding a Firebase-analytics library in pubspec.yaml as it was having Firebase-core issues)

It took another 45 minutes to run from Xcode but it did eventually run. Disappointed with Flutter on getting into issues like this one.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me...

```
cd Project Folder >
rm -R build
rm .dart_tool
rm .packages
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
pod cache clean --all
cd ios > pod deintegrate
pod setup
arch -x86_64 pod install 
cd ..
flutter clean -v
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that my working folder was always being synced to iCloud which causes problems with Xcode. See this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110921

I moved my Github folder with all my projects into my home folder and it works perfectly again.